# Firebase Security Rules: "auth != null" does not work for queries from firebase-admin

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a program which on every page it loads my firebase credentials and initialises auth = firebase.auth(). Furthermore, I also include the auth.onStateChanged function to determine if there is any changes to the authentication state of the user.

However, upon attempting to retrieve information from the database (mainly on the refresh of my page), it says that:

> Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

When I trying to retrieve data from a particular node, **I have the rule "auth != null" and this doesn't work but when I change it too "auth == null" it does work**. Hence, this implies that **auth is not changing in the firebase database rules** even though I have the auth.onStateChange function.

I am able to print the auth variable in the browser console and it is most definitely not null.

**How do I go about fixing this issue on making sure that the auth is being established/connected before allowing the firebase security rules to check the auth variable?**

main.js (client)

```js
var config = {
    apiKey: "X",
    authDomain: "X",
    databaseURL: "X",
    projectId: "X",
    storageBucket: "X",
    messagingSenderId: "X",
    appId: "X",
    measurementId: "X"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.analytics();
var auth = firebase.auth();

auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
  // code for signed in user
  } else {
  // code for not signed in user
  }

});
```

index.js (server)

```js
var firebase = require('firebase/app');

require("firebase/auth");
require('firebase/database');
require("firebase/firestore");
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

var config = {
  apiKey: process.env.APIKEY,
  authDomain: process.env.AUTHDOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.DATABASEURL,
  projectId: process.env.PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: process.env.STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  appId: process.env.APPID,
  measurementId: process.env.MEASUREMENTID
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert('./serviceAccountKeys directory'),
  databaseURL: "X"
});

/*
using firebase commands to access firebase content such as:
  - firebase.database().ref
*/
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

My query is "firebase.database().ref('db-bank/')"

and the database looks like this:

```
/db-bank/content1
```

The firebase rule is:

```
"db-bank": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  ".write": false,
},
```

Comment: Auth does not change "in the rules".  It changes in the client app, and is sent along with your query to be evaluated in the rules on the backend.  But you're not showing the query here, nor are you showing the rules.  Please edit the question to show the code of the query that's failing, along with a line of code that proves that a user is fully signed in just before the query is made (print `firebase.auth().currentUser`).  You should also show your rules.  There should be enough information in the question that anyone can use the duplicate the problem.

Comment: So auth is changing on the client but with my query (i'll edit now), it is not being sent along. After doing "if(user) {}", in onauthstatechange function, I printed the currentuser and it returns an object (not null); so, it should theoretically work in the firebase security rules right?

Comment: Auth information is always sent with every query.  Without seeing your code, we can't see if you might be doing something wrong.  You will need to illustrate that a user is definitely signed in just before the line of code that runs the query.

Comment: I just realised something. Could this be because I am authenticating the user (onauthchange) on the client and I am trying to call the query from the server (where the user isn't technically authenticated)?

Comment: That sounds like an important detail to mention in your question.  We should be able to duplicate the scenario that you explain fully.  Without full repro steps, all we can do is speculate.  I suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: But I said in my question, specifically in the code section of "index.js  (server)" that I queried in there ("/*using firebase commands to access firebase content such as:*/"?)???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code that uses the Firebase Admin SDK on a backend is not affected by security rules.  Read:

- [Does firebase-admin override firestore security rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67788839/does-firebase-admin-override-firestore-security-rules)
- [Is there a way to add security rules that apply to admin in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40548738/is-there-a-way-to-add-security-rules-that-apply-to-admin-in-firebase)

Rules only applies to client app code where a user is actually signed in.